# Zendesk: Make request from within jquery block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zendesk

I am writing a Zendesk App. I need to make an ajax request after selecting something with jquery autocomplete:

```
twTicketsRecvd: function(data) {
  this.$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: descriptions,
    select: function(event,ui){
      this.addTwTicket(event,ui)
    }
  });
},

addTwTicket: function(event,ui) {
  this.ajax('addMapping', 1, 12442)
  //do some other stuff
}
```

I get a *this.addTwTicket is not a function error*

When I put the *this.ajax()* call inside the autocomplete select function, the *this.ajax()* is not found.

This has probably more to do with JS scoping than with zendesk itself, which I am unfortunately not very familiar with.

Comment: What is `this`?  (In context)

Comment: not really sure. i assume it is provided by the zendesk app framework.

Comment: See my answer.  Also, you should be able to `console.log(this)` to see what's in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that within the autocomplete `this` is likely to take on a new definition, so you will want to alias it like so:

```
var _this = this;

twTicketsRecvd: function(data) {
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: descriptions,
    select: function(event,ui){
      _this.addTwTicket(event,ui)
    }
  });
},

addTwTicket: function(event,ui) {
  _this.ajax('addMapping', 1, 12442)
  //do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the zendesk app framework requires a certain format for the js files, as can be seen here: https://github.com/zendesk/demo_apps/blob/master/save_hook_sample_app/app.js  how would i rebind something in this case, as i am basically writing the whole program in a giant map in a return statement

Comment: okay, just realized this was a stupid comment. i was hoping to do it for the whole file, but aliasing it per method works fine. thanks for the help